# png, pdf, tiff margin limitations

Tags: r

In order to get some space for a special ylab text, I use `mar=c(5,7,4,2)`. This provides me with 7 lines of space for ylab. On the default device (screen) everything functions as anticipated. However, I cannot get this output to any other device than the screen.

```
par(mar=c(5,7,4,2))
png(file="a.png", width=500, height=500)
plot(1,1,ylab="A very very long axis title\nthat need special care",xlab="",type="n")
```

I verified the same behavior with png, tiff, pdf. It seems that the maximum printable size in these devices is 4. Anything that goes beyond this number gets cut off. The same behavior is when plotting xlabs, eg by using `mgp=c(5,1,0)`. `mgp=c(4,1,0)` (line 4) is the maximum printable line in any other device than the screen.

Even after upgrading to the latest R version does not change this behavior and it is the same on Windows and Ubuntu.

Any advice on the root cause of this behavior is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the order of your statements.  The `par()` call applies to the current device.  Since you open the `png()` device after that, it doesn't have any effect.  Just put things in this order and they'll be fine:

```r
png(file="a.png", width=500, height=500)
par(mar=c(5,7,4,2))
plot(1,1,ylab="A very very long axis title\nthat need special care",xlab="",type="n")
dev.off()
```

This gives this image in the file:

[image: screen shot of a.png]

Comment: Thank you very much for your appreciated help. That solved the issue and helped understand the root cause.